# ActiveRecord .new not working, any ideas why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know it is broad question but I am really confused.

I have table users and columns :username, :pwd_hash, :first_name, :last_name etc.

When I try to create new instance with

```
user = User.new(:username => 'Foo', first_name => 'Bar')
puts user.inspect
```

and I inspect user I get that all properties set to nil. If I do get existing user all is set properly with User.find(1) so DB is setup correctly. Also there are columns with same name in DB. Using ruby 1.9.3 on Windows.

Again I know it is stupid question but I am despreate I am wondering if anybody had similiar problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen if your User model uses attr_protected or attr_accessible to prevent username or first_name from being mass-assigned.

Comment: Thank you so much, you the man. I worked on this on Friday and completely forgot that that I used it in as:

    attr_accessible :user_attributes

to avoid mass assign warnings. Back to a drawing board but this helped a lot.